# Mapping all unused port slices together

Tags: entity, vhdl

So,

I have a 32 bit port on one of my entities. This is actually made up of lots of smaller signals, all mapped into one register. In one example, when I instantiate it, I am only interested in 3 of the 32 signals. So, I map these accordingly, using a slice association (to a,b and c). I then want to assign the other 29 bits as zero. Is there a quicker way than having to write out several statements to cover all the remaining bits?

```
label: module1
port map(
     reg_in(4) => a,
     reg_in(7) => b,
     reg_in(25)=> c,
     reg_in(3 downto 0) => (others => '0'),
     reg_in(6 downto 5) => (others => '0'),
     reg_in(24 downto 8) => (others => '0'),
     reg_in(31 downto 26) => (others => '0')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an internal signal and connect that in the port map..

```
signal reg_assembly : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
...
reg_assembly <= (4 => a, 7 => b, 25 => c, others => '0');

label: module1
port map(
     reg_in => reg_assembly
);
```